# Reference an issue from a commit message in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, commit, issue-tracking

Is it possible to make a reference to an issue in Gitlab from a commit message?
I haven't found anything on the web.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

There should be a way to reference a GitLab issue from a commit message, simply with `#xx` (id of the issue).
Consider "[Default closing pattern value](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/managing_issues.html#closing-issues-automatically) "

> For example the following commit message:
>
> ```
> Awesome commit message
>
> Fix #20, Fixes #21 and Closes group/otherproject#22.
> This commit is also related to #17 and fixes #18, #19
> and https://gitlab.example.com/group/otherproject/issues/23.
> ```
>
> will close #18, #19, #20, and #21 in the project this commit is pushed to, as well as #22 and #23 in `group/otherproject`.
>
> #17 won't be closed as it does not match the pattern.
>
> It works with multi-line commit messages as well as one-liners when used with `git commit -m`.

See also "[Tutorial: It's all connected in GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/08/gitlab-tutorial-its-all-connected/)"

> Add references in issue or merge request descriptions or in comments.
> This will update the issue with info about anything related.
>
> - To reference an issue: `#123`
> - To reference a MR: `!123`
> - To reference a snippet `$123`

---

[pierreb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4782740/pierreb) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292973/reference-an-issue-from-a-commit-message-in-gitlab?noredirect=1#comment90228725_45294104):

> Although this is not specifically asked in the original question, it may be worth adding that one can also cross-reference a previous commit in a new commit message in Gitlab.
> You do it by copying the hash from the commit message you want to reference and simply pasting it in the new commit message.
> Something along these lines:
>
> ```
> This is related with commit 7as7b101
> ```

You can see (much) more in:

- "[gitlab-ce issue 13345 'ability to reference a commit'](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13345)"
- "[Tutorial: It's all connected in GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/08/gitlab-tutorial-its-all-connected/)".

[andrybak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1083697/andrybak) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292973/reference-an-issue-from-a-commit-message-in-gitlab/45294104#comment136329387_45294104):

> > "You do it by copying the hash from the commit message you want to reference and simply pasting it in the new commit message."
>
> There is also a special, more human-readable format:
>
> ```
> git log -1 --format=reference
>
> <abbrev-hash> (<title-line>, <short-author-date>)
> ```
>
> See [`git log` PRETTY FORMATS](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats)

> This format is used to refer to another commit in a commit message and is the same as `--pretty='format:%C(auto)%h (%s, %ad)'`.
> By default, the date is formatted with `--date=short` unless another `--date option` is explicitly specified.
> As with any `format:` with format placeholders, its output is not affected by other options like `--decorate` and `--walk-reflogs`.

---

[Fr0zenFyr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1369473/fr0zenfyr) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45292973/reference-an-issue-from-a-commit-message-in-gitlab/45294104?noredirect=1#comment97734667_45294104):

> Similarly, even a closed issue can be referenced like `Related to #78 and #93`.

Comment: Although this is not specifically asked in the original question, it may be worth adding that one can also cross-reference a previous commit in a new commit message in Gitlab. You do it by copying the hash from the commit message you want to reference (first eight characters are enough) and simply pasting it in the new commit message. Something along these lines: `This is related with commit 7as7b101`.

Comment: @pierreb Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Similarly, even a closed issue can be referenced like `Related to #78 and #93`

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC What is the syntax for referencing an issue in a different repository? I see you gave an example, could you elaborate?

Comment: @phreed Example: `git commit -m "Awesome commit message (Fixes #21 and Closes group/otherproject#22)"` (which is in my answer): syntax is `group/otherproject#xx`, replace `group/otherproject` by the one of your "different repository".

Comment: re: "You do it by copying the hash from the commit message you want to reference and simply pasting it in the new commit message." – there is also a special, more human-readable format: `git log -1 --format=reference`.  See [section "PRETTY FORMATS" in documentation of `git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats).

Comment: @andrybak Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.